# How to calculate sd(x) using 1 hour rolling window when I have irregular time series data?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo, rollapply

Suppose I have the following zoo object:

```
 prices.zoo <- read.zoo(data.frame(tm = c(as.POSIXct('2000-05-10 07:50:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-05-10 08:55:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-05-10 09:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-05-10 09:10:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-05-10 09:20:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-05-10 09:55:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-05-10 11:35:00')), px = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)))
> prices.zoo
2000-05-10 07:50:00 2000-05-10 08:55:00 2000-05-10 09:00:00 2000-05-10 09:10:00 2000-05-10 09:20:00 2000-05-10 09:55:00 
                 10                  20                  30                  40                  50                  60 
2000-05-10 11:35:00 
                 70
```

How can I calculate sd(px), i.e. historical vol, **EVERY 5 MIN** using a rolling window of 1-HOUR?

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R implementation using zoo or data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width in `rollapplyr` can be a vector indicating how many points to roll over. `findInterval` as used below gives the number of points less than one hour before the current time and if we subtract that from the current position we get the appropriate width.

```
n <- length(prices.zoo)
tt <- time(prices.zoo)
w <- 1:n - findInterval(tt - 3600, tt)
rollapplyr(prices.zoo, w, sd, fill = NA)
## 2000-05-10 07:50:00 2000-05-10 08:55:00 2000-05-10 09:00:00 2000-05-10 09:10:00 
##                  NA                  NA            7.071068           10.000000 
## 2000-05-10 09:20:00 2000-05-10 09:55:00 2000-05-10 11:35:00 
##           12.909944           12.909944                  NA
```

Another possibility is to forget about the 1 hour requirement and just use the last k points.  e.g.

```
rollapplyr(prices.zoo, 3, sd, fill = NA)
## 2000-05-10 07:50:00 2000-05-10 08:55:00 2000-05-10 09:00:00 2000-05-10 09:10:00 
##                  NA                  NA                  10                  10 
## 2000-05-10 09:20:00 2000-05-10 09:55:00 2000-05-10 11:35:00 
##                  10                  10                  10
```

Comment: is there a way to change this so this produces a sd(x) every 5-minutes?

Comment: I mean, we should have an sd(x) value for "2000-05-10 07:50:00", "2000-05-10 07:55:00", "2000-05-10 08:00:00", "2000-05-10 08:05:00", etc.

Comment: I think your first solution is excellent! Thinking about it more, it would work just fine since I am graphing the result. Your 2nd solution won't work for me because a fixed width window won't always work and this is the reason for this question as I am accustomed to fixed windows but I never knew about the first way of doing it. Thanks!